# Activity indicator not loading after performSegue to a ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, segue, activity-indicator

I'm a beginner in Swift and I have a problem about my activity indicator. I've been using NVActivityIndicatorView and I never have any problem until now. I have a LoginViewController which directs to another viewcontroller called ContainerViewController once the user successfully logs in.

LoginViewController:

```
    self.networkManager.getConfig(url: url) { (success, message, response) in
    self.stopAnimating()
        if success {
            print(response)

            if (response[APIKey.error] == nil){
                StoreManager.mainview = Definition(definitionDict: response[APIKey.definition] as! NSDictionary)

                let logoutContextMenu = ContextMenu()
                logoutContextMenu.displayName = Constants.logout
                logoutContextMenu.viewName = Constants.logout
                StoreManager.mainview.contextmenu.append(logoutContextMenu)

                Endpoints.org = StoreManager.mainview.org

                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: Constants.containerViewController , sender: self)
            }

            else{
                self.authenticate()
            }
        }else{
            print(message)
            self.showToast(message: Constants.commonErrorMessage)
        }

    }
```

My problem is once the segue is done, the activityindicator I have in ContainerViewController is not showing while loading the API. This only happens once the user logs in.

In ContainerViewController, I have a function in viewWillLoad called setupUI that will call another function called viewConfig. Inside the viewConfig function is the activity indicator that will start to animate every time the API is loading.

ContainerViewController:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.setUpUI()
}

func setUpUI(){
    switch StoreManager.mainview.menuLayout.mobile {
    case Constants.dashboardmenu:
        setUpSideBarMenu()
        if (otherViewNameSelected){
            print(selectedViewName)
            if selectedViewName == ""{
                selectedViewName = StoreManager.mainview.solutions[0].views[0].viewName
            }
            self.getViewConfig(solutionName: StoreManager.mainview.solutions[0].solutionName, viewName: selectedViewName)
        }

        break

    default:
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil
        break
    }
}

func getViewConfig(){
    let url: String =  Endpoints.view + Endpoints.version + Endpoints.org + "/" + solutionName + "/" + Endpoints.views + viewName + Endpoints.token
    startAnimating()
    networkManager.getConfig(url: url) { (success, message, response) in
        self.stopAnimating()
        if success {
            self.parseViewConfig(response)
        }else{
            print(message)
        }
    }
}
```

parseViewConfig is a function with a tableView inside which loads data.

How can I make the activityindicator show up once the user logs in and ContainerViewController is shown?

Comment: have you try using with ```DispatchQueue.main.async { //add or remove active indicator inside dispatch queue }```

Comment: @Shahrukh where should i put the DispatchQueu.main.async?

Comment: @FayeRañada Put startAnimating() and stopAnimating() in DispatchQueue.main.async { //add or remove active indicator inside dispatch queue }

Comment: @FayeRañada Check my answer

Comment: @Shahrukh nothing change. i still have the same problem.

Comment: https://github.com/ninjaprox/NVActivityIndicatorView/issues Check issues here if any one have same like you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
func getViewConfig(){
    let url: String =  Endpoints.view + Endpoints.version + Endpoints.org + "/" + solutionName + "/" + Endpoints.views + viewName + Endpoints.token
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.startAnimating()
    }
    networkManager.getConfig(url: url) { (success, message, response) in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.stopAnimating()
        }
        if success {
            self.parseViewConfig(response)
        }else{
            print(message)
        }
    }
}
```